# How to animate Newton-Raphson method in Sagemath in a jupyter Notebook?

Tags: graph, jupyter-notebook, sage

How would I go about animating the Newton-Raphson method in Sagemath in a Jupyter notebook?

I have the function

```
f(x)= 4*x^3 - 4*x -1
```

which Ive plotted using

```
plot(f,xmin=-5,xmax=5,ymin=-5,ymax=5)
```

I have found my root using this code many times for increasing values of f

```
f1 = f0 - f(f0)/df(f0) ; f1.n()
```

However my proffessor wants us to animate this method, but Ive never animated something like this before, how would you suggest I go about it?

Comment: you can plot a matplotlib at each iteration, and save it with the number of iteration as name, then you can take all the generated images, feed it in a GIF generator and you have an animation

Comment: That sounds like a good way to do it, however my prof insists on doing it all in the notebook...somehow

Comment: I sued this animation code last time i had to do one https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/, but i don't know what would happen on something like colab...